# React-Native - undefined is not an object ("evaluating this._component.getScrollableNode")

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm snuggling using react native, I'm not able to run my application.

I updated my `react-native` version from `"^0.46.4"` to `0.47.1` because  `^0.46.4` I had a different error and  `react` from `^15.6.1` to  `16.0.0-alpha.12`,
the previous error was

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_reactNative.PropTypes.string')

that refers to this the update after react 15.5
 https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html

so I updated it using

`npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade`

and then

`react-native-git-upgrade`

according to this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

`"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12"`,
`"react-native": "^0.47.1"`,

And I'm still having this error.. 
I'll appreciate any help

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: yes I added my answer I hope that works for u

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do it. Also forgot to import it :) lol

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix it and basically the third party folder was not autogenerating...
[image]

after awhile I update my versions to 0.47.2 and I also updated my dependencies to latest version to avoid deprecated issues (Due to the new react native version deprecated a createJSModules method in java) then I removed the node_modules folder and run

```
npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade

and then

react-native-git-upgrade

npm install
```